# How to get multiple queries return in the right order?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, request

Below is a very simple code sample. There is a search input box at the top of the interface and data below. When you type text into the input, it filters the data showed below in the interface. So each time the user types a letter, there will be a request to get the data. For example, if you type "folder", you will get all the data that has the word "folder" in it.

The problem is that when you type really fast, the first query results (for letter f) are return last. The reason for that is simple: since the search is based on only one letter, the results are huge. So for the word "folder", we get the results for the word "f".

Do you have any idea of what I can do, which approach I should use?

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<IItems[]>([]);

const getItems = async (searchFilter: string): Promise<void> => {
   const data: IItems[] = await getData(searchFilter);
   setItems(data);
}

useEffect(() => {
   getItems(searchFilter);
},[searchFilter]);
```

Comment: Use the effect cleanup function, to abort the `getData` query (or at least prevent the `setItems` call) after the `searchFilter` has changed.

Comment: Alternatively, a short debounce time will prevent the search term from being submitted to the function until the user hasn't entered any more input for the given period of time. Lots of UI library components support this out the box, but it should be too hard to implement your own if you have to.

Comment: @Stitt While that's a good suggestion, it doesn't prevent the asynchronous responses from potentially occurring out of order.

Comment: @Bergi I disagree, the entire premise of the async requests being out of order is wrong. If I type `folder`, as in the example given, I don't want to see results for `f`, `fold`, etc. Only making the request once the user has actually entered their full search term makes the most sense logically

Comment: @Stitt What if you type `fold`, pause, then type `er`? And even if you don't use arbitrary pauses to detect that the search term was "fully" entered, but use a proper submit button to avoid guessing the user's intentions, the issue with responses coming in different order than the requests are sent is not solved.

Comment: In that instance I would expect that you entirely discard the previous result, as its now irrelevant. From a UX perspective, a combination of debounce (to not start searching prematurely) and cleanup (to keep search results relevant) is ideal

Answer (score 1):

I think @Bergi's answer is right, so I have practiced that. This approach should solve the issue of receiving results out of order when typing quickly in the search box.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState<IItems[]>([]);
const [searchFilter, setSearchFilter] = useState('');

const getItems = async (searchFilter: string, signal: AbortSignal): Promise<void> => {
   try {
       const data: IItems[] = await getData(searchFilter, signal);
       setItems(data);
   } catch (error) {
       if (error.name !== 'AbortError') {
           console.error('Fetch error:', error);
       }
   }
}

useEffect(() => {
   const controller = new AbortController();
   const signal = controller.signal;

   getItems(searchFilter, signal);

   return () => controller.abort();
}, [searchFilter]);

async function getData(filter: string, signal: AbortSignal): Promise<IItems[]> {
    // ... your existing logic to fetch data
    // fetch(url, { signal })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Debounce the user input, you can use a debounce function to delay the invocation of `getItems` after the user has finished typing. You can utilize the `useDebounce` hook from the `use-debounce` package to simplify the debounce functionality. First, you need to install the package:

```
npm install use-debounce
```

Then, you can use it in your component like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import useDebounce from 'use-debounce';

const [items, setItems] = useState<IItems[]>([]);
const [debouncedSearchFilter] = useDebounce(searchFilter, 300);

const getItems = async (searchFilter: string): Promise<void> => {
  const data: IItems[] = await getData(debouncedSearchFilter);
  setItems(data);
};

useEffect(async () => {
  await getItems(debouncedSearchFilter);
}, [debouncedSearchFilter]);
```

It will fire the method after the user has stopped typing for 300ms.

Comment: This does not solve the issue with  `setItems` calls happening out of order.

Comment: Move the **getItems** method out of **useEffect** and call it using await.

Comment: That makes even less sense, it violates the principles of React